# How to allow post_to_twitter only once(on create or on update)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a **tweeted** field in my model.
When user creates a new **post** he can check out a checkbox that will also make  a posting to twitter.

```
  after_create :post_to_twitter, if: :tweeted
```

If the checkbox was checked on **create**, it'll be hidden from user on other updates of the post.

```
<% unless @post.tweeted? %>
  <%= f.input :tweeted, inline_label: "Tweet this", as: :boolean %>
<% end %>
```

But if user didn't check it on **create** how can I allow it to be checked on **update** only once.

So posting to twitter can be performed only once on **create** or **update**. After the tweet was posted the checkbox should be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as the following in your model:

```
after_create :tweet_with_condition

def tweet_with_condition
 if tweeted_changed? && tweeted.present?
    # post to twitter code blocks or method
 end 
end
```

In your form you should do something like following. Where you can set 2 condition. One is checking if @post is a new record or the post has not tweeted yet.

```
  <%= f.input :tweeted, inline_label: "Tweet this", as: :boolean if @post.new_record? or !@post.tweeted? %>
```

Comment: it makes a posting on create but nothing happens on update. But I think this is almost what I need.

Comment: Oh, it works just fine when I call tweet_with_condition for both after_create and after_update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is updating the post for the first time by checking that the created_at and updated_at timestamp for the post are same.

```
<% if !@post.tweeted? && (@post.created_at == @post.updated_at) %>
  <%= f.input :tweeted, inline_label: "Tweet this", as: :boolean %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I know how to hide the checkbox depending on conditions. I don't know how to set up my model properly.